# Why does this transition only work with no outline?

Tags: html, css

```css
input {
  border: 3px solid #FFEFD5;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input:focus {
  border: 3px solid #CD853F;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Click Here!">
</form>
```

If i delete the outline setting, the transition doesn't work.
Why does this happen? Please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: seems to work even if I remove `outline: none`. Can you help us replicate the problem?

Comment: Maybe your outline merges with border and you simply do not see it? Because on FF I can see outline _and_ border on focused item

Comment: if i change the input:focus border color from #CD853F into White and click the box, the border's color changes blue not white. why this happens?

Comment: That blue is the browser’s default `outline`, not the `border`. If you set `outline: none`, you prevent the browser from setting its default.

Comment: For Chrome on macOS, the browser's default outline style is immediately shown on focus. And this is overlaying the border, so you don't see the border animation, on blur the outline immediately disappears and you see the transition of the border back to its original state. Is that what you are observing?

Comment: yeah It seems the browser's outline..... feeling empty a little... Anyway, really thank you for all your advices..!!

Answer (score -4):

Just add `box-sizing: border-box;` in the main class and add a custom outline in the focus class.

```
input {
  border: 3px solid #FFEFD5;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #FF0000; /* Your Custom Outline Here */
  border: 3px solid #CD853F;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

it's because to have some kind of transition you have to set the initial and final properties for it in your case if you delete the border in your main element the initial condition gets deleted.

So, the solution is to make the initial condition not visible so you have some property but it's not visible in your condition making border thickness 0px or making your border color to transparent.

I have attached both solutions.

```css
input {
  border: 0 solid #FFEFD5;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input:focus {
  border: 3px solid #CD853F;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Click Here!">
</form>
```

```css
input {
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input:focus {
  border: 3px solid #CD853F;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="Click Here!">
</form>
```

Comment: This answer neither explains the phenomenon in question, nor solves it.

Comment: @cSharp
I edited the answer, maybe it's more understanding now.

Comment: @wogur016 if this answer is what you are looking for please upvote and make it the correct answer for this question.

Comment: Actually my problem was the browser's characteristic. So i already solved it. but i appreciate your help!